# Drop n' swap text chunks with GAE Blobstore API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, file-io, blobstore

I am designing a GAE app that will allow a user to upload a PDF file, whereby I'll save it off to the GAE Blobstore.

I need the ability to "drop n' swap" chunks of text in these blobstored files. That is, I need the ability to cherry pick a particular sentence out of the file (stored in the Blobstore), and replace it with different text.

Say I have a PDF file, and I know that starting at the 505th byte/character in the file, there is the sentence:

> The woods are lovely, dark and deep.

And I want to replace (drop n' swap) that sentence with:

> But I have promises to keep.

Then I know that I want to replace bytes 505 through 541 (*The woods are lovely, dark and deep.*) with my new string.

So I ask: **is this possible?** I see that the Blobstore API allows you to read a specific segment of characters from a stored blob:

```
// Now contains: "The woods are lovely, dark and deep."
String toDropNSwap = blobStoreService.fetchData(blobKey, 505, 541);

toDropNSwap = "But I have promises to keep.";

// This doesn't exist, just an example:
blobstoreService.dropAndSwap(505, 541, toDropNSwap);
```

But I don't see how I can replace a segment of bytes with another segment of bytes, especially if the new segment is a different size. And one more thing: I'll be working with files up to 20MB in size. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blobs are [immutable](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Introducing_the_Blobstore):

> Blobs can't be modified after they're created, though they can be
>   deleted. Each blob has a corresponding blob info record, stored in the
>   datastore, that provides details about the blob, such as its creation
>   time and content type. You can use the blob key to fetch blob info
>   records and query their properties.

So what you are looking for is not possible. You will have to delete and create a new blob instead.